# Error 2 while building project in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, rtems, rcc

16:22:14 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project ccsds-compression.git.old **** 
make all
'Building file: ../../src/AC_Coding.c' 
sparc-leon3-none-gcc.exe -c -O3 -pedantic -Wall -msoft-float -mcpu=v8 -mtune=leon -Wno-long-long -funroll-loops -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -I. -I....\src -o AC_Coding.o ../../src/AC_Coding.c process_begin: CreateProcess((null), sparc-leon3-none-gcc.exe -c -O3 -pedantic -Wall -msoft-float -mcpu=v8 -mtune=leon -Wno-long-long -funroll-loops -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -I. -I....\src -o AC_Coding.o ../../src/AC_Coding.c, ...) failed. make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [AC_Coding.o] Error 2

I am receiving this error when building the project. Could someone guide me as to how I should resolve this?

Comment: "How should I resolve this" 1) RTFM 2) If that is still not clear, provide a [mcve].

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified". So make it find it.

Comment: The manual asks me to replace the clean rule as  mingw32-make was unable to find the utility "rm". That didn't change anything as I use MSYS instead. I am new at this..